# i've tried various element search methods like class, name, and id, but it's not working

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, winhttp

I've been attempting Excel Web Scraping with WinHTTP, and I've tried various element search methods like class, name, and id, but it's not working. Scraping works on other sites, but it's not working well on this website. What I want to scrape is the product name and the URL of the picture. Can anyone help?
the code is below

```
Sub WebScrapingWithWinHTTP()
    Dim objWinHTTP As Object
    Set objWinHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    Dim url As String
    url = "https://www.outre.com/new/"

    objWinHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    objWinHTTP.send

    Dim html As String
    html = objWinHTTP.responseText

   
    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = html

    
    Dim elements As Object
    Set elements = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("uppercase.font-bold.text-[16px].xs:text-[1.3vw].lg:text-[14px]")

    If elements.Length > 0 Then
        Dim element As Object
        Set element = elements.Item(1)
        Dim title As String
        title = element.innertext
    
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = title
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "nothing"
    End If

    Set objWinHTTP = Nothing
    Set htmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your expected ouput?

Comment: "I want to put the product names in column A and the product picture URLs in column B in excel sheet.

Comment: If the listing on the page is created dynamically after the page loads, you can't use this approach to get what you want - you need to use browser automation with (eg) Selenium.